# Call a partial from AJAX URL Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

How can I call a partial from an Ajax function, I need to render the content of a partial inside my home.html.erb, here the code:

```
<div class="span8">
  <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
    <div class="posts">
        <%= render 'feed' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

At bottom I have a script, the problem code are in these lines:

```
if(nearBottomOfPage()) {
  loading=true;
  page++;
  $.ajax({ // send an ajax-request to load the next page
    url: '/feed?page=' + page,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function() { // after successfully completing the ajax-request redraw the    sausage-navigation.
      $(window).sausage('draw');
      loading=false;
    }
  });
```

The "url" parameter is where I don't know what to write to call a partial, this partial is call _feed.html.erb and It's inside the same folder of Home.html.erb, finaly in my controller action I have this:

```
def home
  if signed_in?
    @post  = current_user.posts.build
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.order(:created_at).page(params[:page])
  end  
  respond_to do |format|
      format.js  { render :partial => 'feed'}
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @feed_items }
    end
 end
```

How can I call that partial from the Ajax function?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant call the partial directly via a URL. Only pages/views in the /public dir can be accessed directly.

You need to create a controller action that renders the 'feed' partial, and a corresponding route. Then use the path for that route as your AJAX URL.

Comment: Then I have the content that I need at feed.html.erb, how can I render it by escape_javascript(????) :s